# Issue with client requesting Azure API Management endpoint - Error: ClientConnectionFailure: at transfer-response

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have a nodejs client making request to an azure api management endpoint. I am getting the following exception sometimes:

`ClientConnectionFailure: at transfer-response`

So i am using the request package, and in the client i am doing a straightforward request:

```
request({
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "contentType": "application/json",
                "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": key
            },
            uri: endpointUrl
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            (...)
        });
```

So is it a timeout eventually happening in the client, in the middle of the request, and consequently failing the connection with the Azure APIM endpoint?
Or something else? And how do you think i could solve this problem? I thought about increase the timeout in the request, but i am assuming that in omission of timeout, it is assuming the default timeout of the server (Azure Function App) that is 120 seconds, right?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your function take long to process without APIM too? If not, could you check the [trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-api-inspector) to see what's happening?

Comment: This is an intermittent issue, so it is hard to trace the request, because i am not able to reproduce it. Also, the back end function, called by the apim instance, is running under standard plan, so i would say it should be fine in terms of performance. According to App Insights, in the last 30 days, the maximum executiond duration of the function was 18,040.338 MS = 0.3 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ClientConnectionFailure` suggests that client broke the connection wile APIM was processing request. `at transfer-response` means that this happened when APIM was sending response to client. APIM does not cache request/response body by default, so when it's sending response to client it's at the same time reading it from backend. This may lead to client breaking off the connection if backend takes too long to respond with actual data.

This behavior is driven purely by client deciding to stop waiting for data. Check how long it takes for you on client before you send request and see the error. Try adjusting client timeout.

Comment: We decided to contact Microsoft support, and after analysis of the logs, the client (function app) is closing the connection before the APIM instance finishes to transfer all info, consequently the APIM raises that error. Anyway thanks all for the help

Comment: @HugoBarona hey what was the fix for your client (function app) that Microsoft suggested? I m facing same issue and looking for a possible solution. here is the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70512357/jmeter-load-test-of-50-users-requesting-azure-api-management-endpoint-error-c/70516488#70516488

Comment: @user42012 I responded to your thread with my findings. Let me know how it goes. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you @HugoBarona, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

We have seen this behavior when the back end is taking too long to respond.

My approach would be to take a look at the backend first which is Function app in this case and see the time taken and **then see if there are any** [timeout limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies) **set at APIM.**

The timeout duration of a function app is defined by the functionTimeout property in the [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout) project file. The following table shows the default and maximum values in minutes for both plans and in both runtime versions:

[image]

For troubleshooting Performance issue , follow this [Troubleshoot slow app performance issues in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-performance-degradation)

Comment: We have in the back end a function app, using Standard app service plan. The runtime is 1x. i have no timeout in the host file. the apim instance, i have no policies for timeouts. Is there any chance of the timeout to happen in the client, calling the apim instance? the client is a function app running on consumption plan and it has no timeout conifgured on host file, but it is doing a request to the instance. So, my point is, is it possible, according to the exception, that the communication is breaking in the client side and not the back end side?

Comment: Regardless of the function app timeout setting, 230 seconds is the maximum amount of time that an HTTP triggered function can take to respond to a request. This is because of the default idle timeout of Azure Load Balancer.

Comment: Well these functions are triggered by an event grid event. But even considering the same timeout, 230 seconds => 3.83 minutes. My client function has the slowest execution as 76 seconds in the last 30 days. My back end function, called by the apim instance, has max of 0.3 minutes of execution in the last 30 days.