# Jmeter Load test of 50 users requesting Azure API Management endpoint - Error: ClientConnectionFailure: at transfer-response

Tags: jmeter, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-api-management

We have an Azure application where Functions Apps (Backend) which talks to Azure SQL Server and is front-ended thru API Management service (and we have App gateway thru which the APIs are called).
Application works fine as such but as soon as we are doing load testing with 50 to 100 concurrent users we see some of the requests with (ClientConnectionFailure:
at transfer-response).

```
[{"severityLevel":"Error","outerId":"0","message":"Client connection was unexpectedly closed.","type":"ClientConnectionFailure","id":"0","parsedStack":[{"method":"transfer-response","level":0,"line":0}]}]
```

I have checked the trace table on Application Insights and I dont see any failure so I am not sure if this is causing from the JMeter load test client that the connection is getting dropped before the response is coming from Server under load.

Anyone face issue like this and found a fix? We are running with Premium Service plan and as such dont see major issues with our Service or SQL calls.

Appreciate your help.

Thank you,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with client requesting Azure API Management endpoint - Error: ClientConnectionFailure: at transfer-response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938872/issue-with-client-requesting-azure-api-management-endpoint-error-clientconnec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [my initial thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938872/issue-with-client-requesting-azure-api-management-endpoint-error-clientconnec/55976227?noredirect=1#comment124656475_55976227) reporting this issue, and besides the fact that the comments and response are talking about the timeout in the backend, there was no evidence that the backend was performing poorly. I check the logs and as I mentioned in the original thread, the backend and the client apps had low response times (<1min) to cause the timeout. So I started to explore a different option, in this case, the number of requests performed at the same time to the APIM, and I would say if you perform a significant number of requests at the same time, some of them will start to queue, and depending on how long they will be queued, potentially the client will start to timeout. So as far as I remember, I throttled the scalability of the azure functions to do not scale massively. Or if you do not want to go in that direction, you can try the [Premium Plan on Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale)

Comment: Thank you Hugo, we are using the Premium App service plan here and we are testing with 100 concurrent users which is not that high of a number. Our functions are taking about 4 to 5 seconds after certain load and overall about 1 or 2mins cause of the client connection failure.  I will keep exploring to find out whats going on and report back here on this thread.

Comment: Try to decrease the number of concurrent users (instances of functions) and see if the error still persists. Also, which tier are you using in your APIM instance? Maybe upgrading the tier would be worth trying out?

Comment: Thank you @Hugo,  I am on Premium tier for APIM as well and the concurrency is part of the load test (100 concurrent users doing same operation) so unfortunately I cant reduce that number from Jmeter as that's what the customer wants to see the response times. Since we are are on App Service Plan P1V2 really not sure on how the instances can be reduced here.

Comment: Try maybe to reduce the timeout to just a few seconds (enough to complete a normal request) and then see how many timeout, so you have an idea of how many requests are queuing.

Comment: Also, I noticed that you have a Function connecting directly to the Azure Sql server (Azure SQL Db?!?) and Azure APIM. Since you have requirements in terms of concurrency, you may be limited in terms of the level of concurrency, unless you run multiple instances of the DB and ensure they serve the different requests. If you can consider processing those requests in async mode, then I would suggest you have a look at this pattern. It may help mitigate all these problems -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/queue-based-load-leveling

Comment: If the async mode does not work in your environment, then try to do the following. Comment out the code lines in the Az Function to make the connection to the DB, and just leave the function there receiving the requests and doing nothing. And try to run the load testing again, to see if it is the DB slowing down the process and causing the queueing or if it is the APIM causing the queuing. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @Hugo, appreciate your detailed follow up and I like your suggestion on identifying the bottle neck here by commenting out DB code. I will go with that and test out few functions we have to rule out Azure App service (or the DB).

Comment: @user42012 did you find a solution or root cause?

Comment: @J.Kirk. we had issues with our SQL Code. Basically we were doing INSERT and SELECT in the same set of transaction causing a lot of locks on SQL. We went with MERGE and also moved the inline SQL to stored procs to get around this issue and for now we are not having any performance issues and also no client connection failures.

Answer (score 1):

If the error is reproducible only under the load I would assume that at certain point either your function or database response time exceeds the JMeter's timeout.

By default JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers don't have any timeout defined which means that JMeter will wait for the response forever, however there could be timeouts on JDK and operating system level so it might be a good idea to set some reasonable value there.

The timeout settings live under "Advanced" tab. If you have more than one HTTP Request sampler - consider introducing [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) so you could amend the setting at one place and the change will be propagated to all the HTTP Request samplers in the HTTP Requests Defaults [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules).

[image]

If this doesn't help - check your network infrastructure: routers, gateways, firewalls, load balancers, etc. as each of them could have its own timeout settings.

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri-T I will look into changing this setting and observe it under load if at all this helps. Our Infra is all Azure so I m less inclined on that but also I am going to try and load test just the function app to see the behavior as well.